# Getting a weird output on my program lost on what to do next to fix it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So i've ben at this program for awhile and i've gotten everything to work without compiling error but now I'm getting a weird output, first ill post the program the the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class project3 {

    private static double[] payrate;
    private static String[] names;

    public static void SortData(double payrate[]) {
        int first;
        int temp;
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = payrate.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            first = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (payrate[j] < payrate[first]) {
                    first = j;
                }
            }
            temp = (int) payrate[first];
            payrate[first] = payrate[i];
            payrate[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void GetData() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
        String strNum = input.nextLine();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
        int array[] = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            names = new String[num];
            System.out.println("enter employee's name: ");
            names[i] = input.nextLine();
                            //while(names[i].length < 2)
            //{
            //System.out.println("enter valid employee's name: ");

                            //names[i] = input.nextLine(); 
            //} 
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            payrate = new double[num];
            System.out.println("enter employee's payrate: ");
            payrate[j] = input.nextDouble();
            while (payrate[j] > 100 || payrate[j] < 0) {
                System.out.println("enter valid employee's payrate: ");
                payrate[j] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DisplayData(double payrate[], String names[]) {

        System.out.printf("Name    PayRate\n");
        for (int l = 0; l < names.length; l++) {
            //for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
            // {
            System.out.print(names[l]);
            System.out.printf("\n", payrate[l]);
            //} 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetData();
        SortData(payrate);
        DisplayData(payrate, names);

    }
}
```

The program Is suppose to print out something like this

```
Name      Payrate
Daniel    54.76
josh      73.12
kyle      12.54
```

but the program is printing out this

```
Name    PayRate
null
null
null
null
qt
```

Comment: 1. Time to do some debugging with a debugger preferably or with a bunch of println statements. You can do this, but it will take a little effort. 2) If still stuck, then show the results of your debugging attempts, and also 3) please work on improving your posted code formatting. It's hard enough to try to understand someone else's code, you don't want to make it harder by random use of indentation. Indentation of code in a block should be uniform, not haphazard.

Comment: You have this `names = new String[num];` ***inside*** the `for` loop. What do you think will happen with the first entered name, when the program creates a new String array and stores the second name in there? (repost to fix typo)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some point you can correct it.

1. in `GetData()`, you should put `names = new String[num];` anywhere
   before loop start, so deos `payrate = new double[num];`.
2. in `SortData()`, why not use `double temp;`? then you don't have to turn `payrate[first]` into int type.
3. in `DisplayData()`, `System.out.printf("\n", payrate[l]);` disply
       nothing but change line. I think it's better to do like

   ```
   System.out.printf("Name\tPayRate\n");
   for (int l = 0; l < names.length; l++) {
       System.out.print(names[l]);
       System.out.println("\t"+payrate[l]);
   }
   ```

---

well, it's eaiser to explain with code than English.  :'(

```
public static void SortData(double payrate[]) {
    int first;
    double temp;
    String tempString;
    int i;
    int j;        
    for (i = payrate.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        first = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (payrate[j] < payrate[first]) {
                first = j;
            }
        }
        temp = payrate[first];
        payrate[first] = payrate[i];
        payrate[i] = temp;

        tempString = names[first];
        names[first] = names[i];
        names[i] = tempString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, But now With my sort data its not keeping the sorted data to the right names, I thought it would order the arrays but keep the same variable suchs as payrate[0] and names[0] would stay together in my display data but now it switches the payrates around, any tips on how I should go about fixing this?

Comment: you only sort `payrate` in the code.  you can simply copy `temp = (int) payrate[first];
            payrate[first] = payrate[i];
            payrate[i] = temp;
`  and turn one of it `payrate` to `names`

Comment: notice you need a `String type variable` instead of `temp`

Comment: Sorry I'm having a trouble with understanding what you mean, like do something like,             names[i] = temp;

Comment: Thanks! one more question so this I'm trying to create a control loop that says if the name is less than 2 characters it makes it the user enter another name why is this loop not working?while(names[i].length < 2)
         {
               System.out.println("enter valid employee's name: ");
               
               names[i] = input.nextLine(); 
         }

Comment: it shoud be `names[i].length()`